# R: One label situated wrong

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I have made the following plot using this code,

[image: pie chart with bad label]

however as u can see in the picture, the label for "Mittlere Reife" (16,2%) is not where its supposed to be. Every other label is situated perfectly, and I cant figure out why the one just won´t work. Thanks for your help ;)

Editdput(Bildung):

```
Bildung <- structure(list(Q4 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("Andere", 
"Qualifizierter Hauptschulabschluss", "Mittlere Reife", "Fachabitur/Allgemeines Abitur", 
"Universitätsabschluss"), class = "factor"), n = c(1L, 5L, 42L, 
72L, 139L), perc = c(0.00386100386100386, 0.0193050193050193, 
0.162162162162162, 0.277992277992278, 0.536679536679537), labels = c("0.4%", 
"1.9%", "16.2%", "27.8%", "53.7%")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))    

ggplot(Bildung, aes(x="", y= perc, fill=Q4)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  geom_label(aes(label = labels),
             position = position_dodge2(width =1),
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+
  theme_void()+
  labs(fill = "Bildungsgrad")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, 'cm'))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Tbh I dont know how to do that, but I added a picture of the data frame used in the plot.

Comment: Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). The link I included shows lots of ways to include data. The most common is to use `dput(Bildung)`

Comment: Didnt notice u included a link, sorry. I used dput now and included the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the labels in the center of the slices, you need to calculate those values yourself. Here's one way to do this using `dplyr`

```
Bildung %>% 
  arrange(desc(Q4)) %>% 
  mutate(midpoint = cumsum(perc)-perc/2) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x=1, y=perc, fill=Q4)) +
  geom_col(width=1) +
  geom_label(aes(label = labels,  x=seq(1.5,.7,length.out=5), y=midpoint),
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+
  theme_void()+
  labs(fill = "Bildungsgrad")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, 'cm'))
```

This returns

[image: labeled pie]